# Magento 1.9: JS File in browser does not change

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, cache, redis

I'm using extension Cm_RedisSession to enable Redis, when i change a js file in media/js folder, and when I reload the browser it still didn't change, i already did these:

1. Delete `var/cache` , `var/session`
2. Flush Magento Cache
3. Delete Browser Cache
4. Using other browser and pc
5. Flush Redis Cache `redis-cli flushall`

Comment: Please check is there any access log when requesting the js file edited and also check is there any CDN using

Comment: @L.C.EchoChan i'm using cloudflare CDN

Comment: CDN will do a caching on the JS file. It will take times to update the JS file.

Comment: Try to enable the Development Mode on cloudflare to see solve or not